# Server error when launching jupyter notebook in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: permissions, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to get Jupyter notebook in wsl with [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/kauffmanes/5e74916617f9993bc3479f401dfec7da) and I got a server error in `http://localhost:8889/tree`. I don't know if it is important:

```
Server error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py",
line 1592, in _execute result = yield result File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run value = future.result() File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py",
line 326, in wrapper yielded = next(result) File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py",
line 112, in get path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content, File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py",
line 431, in get model = self._dir_model(path, content=content) File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py",
line 337, in _dir_model if self.should_list(name) and not is_file_hidden(os_path, stat_res=st): File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py",
line 145, in is_file_hidden_posix stat_res = os.stat(abs_path) 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Application Data'
```

And in wsl terminal:

```
(base) antoi@LAPTOP-UTL8OHHO:/mnt/c/Users/antoi$ jupyter notebook --no-browser
[I 16:19:55.476 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 16:19:55.505 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 16:19:55.506 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/antoi/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 16:19:55.532 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /mnt/c/Users/antoi
[I 16:19:55.533 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:19:55.534 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=6e5f12a846547af4515d05140a142a60945bae661cce6571
[I 16:19:55.551 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:19:55.566 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=6e5f12a846547af4515d05140a142a60945bae661cce6571
[I 16:20:02.914 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=6e5f12a846547af4515d05140a142a60945bae661cce6571 (127.0.0.1) 0.44ms
[E 16:20:03.523 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1582129203252 (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8889', method='GET', uri='/api/contents?type=directory&_=1582129203252', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1592, in _execute
        result = yield result
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
        path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 431, in get
        model = self._dir_model(path, content=content)
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 337, in _dir_model
        if self.should_list(name) and not is_file_hidden(os_path, stat_res=st):
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 145, in is_file_hidden_posix
        stat_res = os.stat(abs_path)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Application Data'
[W 16:20:03.528 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 16:20:03.529 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8889",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Accept-Language": "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|2adc4da8|04ae20472b692936cf36fbc3b6869509|1581352093",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8889/tree",
      "Cookie": "username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1581936567|23:username-localhost-8888|44:ZjIyODAyNzlmYTAxNGE0MTljODBmNGU3MGJlMmZmZGI=|ca6177ff5468b65d9b1202ac00c91c3c0536635c39d430be915f2b96ee1c2934\"; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1582129202|23:username-localhost-8889|44:OWNhNzhlM2E2Yzc3NDc1NDlkNWQ1NzAwZGRlZGU5N2Q=|e22d8c299570cd29dd8933e8f60b6481cd5aa78d972d6d4fd2258c630440915c\"; _xsrf=2|2adc4da8|04ae20472b692936cf36fbc3b6869509|1581352093",
      "Dnt": "1"
    }
[E 16:20:03.547 NotebookApp] 500 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1582129203252 (127.0.0.1) 18.27ms referer=http://localhost:8889/tree
[E 16:25:22.478 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1582129203255 (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8889', method='GET', uri='/api/contents?type=directory&_=1582129203255', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1592, in _execute
        result = yield result
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/handlers.py", line 112, in get
        path=path, type=type, format=format, content=content,
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 431, in get
        model = self._dir_model(path, content=content)
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 337, in _dir_model
        if self.should_list(name) and not is_file_hidden(os_path, stat_res=st):
      File "/home/antoi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/utils.py", line 145, in is_file_hidden_posix
        stat_res = os.stat(abs_path)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Application Data'
[W 16:25:22.589 NotebookApp] Unhandled error
[E 16:25:22.589 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8889",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
      "Accept-Language": "fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "X-Xsrftoken": "2|2adc4da8|04ae20472b692936cf36fbc3b6869509|1581352093",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8889/tree",
      "Cookie": "username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1581936567|23:username-localhost-8888|44:ZjIyODAyNzlmYTAxNGE0MTljODBmNGU3MGJlMmZmZGI=|ca6177ff5468b65d9b1202ac00c91c3c0536635c39d430be915f2b96ee1c2934\"; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1582129202|23:username-localhost-8889|44:OWNhNzhlM2E2Yzc3NDc1NDlkNWQ1NzAwZGRlZGU5N2Q=|e22d8c299570cd29dd8933e8f60b6481cd5aa78d972d6d4fd2258c630440915c\"; _xsrf=2|2adc4da8|04ae20472b692936cf36fbc3b6869509|1581352093",
      "Dnt": "1"
    }
[E 16:25:22.625 NotebookApp] 500 GET /api/contents?type=directory&_=1582129203255 (127.0.0.1) 122.78ms referer=http://localhost:8889/tree
```